# "InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' has been registered."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm somewhat of a newbie to programming, and very much a newbie to c# and .NET Core.

I'm having some difficulty trying to ascertain why this simple "hello world" app is failing with the error in my title.

I'm trying to have the application read the "Hello!!" from appsettings.json and display it on the screen.

Here is my Startup.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace My_NET_Core_Test_2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                                IHostingEnvironment env, 
                                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                                IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var greeting = configuration["Greeting"];
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(greeting);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace My_NET_Core_Test_2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Greeting":  "Hello!!",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but where do you register an implementation of `IConfiguration`?  Take a look at [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/04/26/setting-up-net-core-configuration-providers/)

Comment: It looks like you're using an older version of ASP.NET Core (if not, you're using an old approach). Which version are you actually using?

Comment: What is your project version? I made a test with your code under .net core 2.1, I only need to configure the `appsettings.json` by `            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
               .UseKestrel()
               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
               {
                   config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
               })
               .UseIISIntegration()
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();
`

Comment: Hmm.  I've tried setting my project's target framework to .NET Core 2.1 (before I was using 1.1), and I'm getting the same result.  When I try updating my Program.cs Main method to use Tao Zhou's suggested code, Visual Studio doesn't seem to like the ConfigureAppConfiguration line.  "IWebHostBuilder does not contain a definition for..."

Answer (score 2):

This issue occours becasue the IConfiguration instance can't be resolved. You can define the instance in the Startup constructor via the [ConfigurationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which let's you define from where the configuration values should be taken from.

Here's a basic example where the ConfigurationBuilder will read values from the appsettings.json in the content root path and read environment variables.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                            IHostingEnvironment env, 
                            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            var greeting = _configuration["Greeting"];
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(greeting);
        });
    }
}
```